# How to export Excel file from Angular Material 5 Mat-Table (Angular Material Table)?

Tags: excel, angular-material, angular5, xlsx, sheetjs

I am new to Angular and using Angular material 5 mat-table and trying to export the table in a excel file. I have use **SheetJS XLSX** package.

Below is my code:

**Table.component.html:**

```
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

      <!-- ID Column -->
      <!--<ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> UserID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.UserID}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>-->

      <!-- Progress Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="MSID">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> MSID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.MSID}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="MSPW">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> MS Password </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.MSPW}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="MSRequsest">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> MS Requsest </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.MSRequsest}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="ClassID">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Class ID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.ClassID}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="ClassName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Class Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.ClassName}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="FirstName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.FirstName}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="LastName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.LastName}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Email">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Email}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Role">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Role </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.EmployeeRole}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeRoleFrom">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee Role From </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.EmployeeRoleFrom}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="VendorID">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Vendor ID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.VendorID}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="VendorNameCompany">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Vendor Name Company </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.VendorNameCompany}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="StaffID">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Staff ID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.StaffID}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Source">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Source </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Source}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="HireDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Hire Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.HireDate}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="HireType">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Hire Type </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.HireType}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="EnteredDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Entered Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.EnteredDate}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="FloorDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Floor Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.FloorDate}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="SiteLocation">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Site Location </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.SiteLocation}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeContractorID">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee Contractor ID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.EmployeeContractorID}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="TransferFrom">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Transfer From </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.TransferFrom}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Notes">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Notes </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Notes}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Status}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Action Column -->


      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
      </mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

**Table.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';    
import { WorkflowService } from "../workflow.service";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';    
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx/xlsx'; 
    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-doc',
  templateUrl: './table-doc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-doc.component.css']
})

export class TableDocComponent implements OnInit {

 @ViewChild('TABLE') table: ElementRef;
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
   displayedColumns = ['MSID','MSPW','MSRequsest','ClassID','ClassName',
   'FirstName','LastName','Email','Role','EmployeeRoleFrom','VendorID',
   'VendorNameCompany','StaffID','Source','HireDate','HireType','EnteredDate',
  'FloorDate','SiteLocation','EmployeeContractorID','TransferFrom','Notes','Status',
  ];  
 
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();   
    constructor( private http:HttpClient,private workflowService : WorkflowService,private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

  ngOnInit() {
   
     this.tableDataSource();         
  }

ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
     this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
   }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
 
tableDataSource(){
 this.workflowService.GetUploadDocData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataSource.data = data ;
       
      }  
    );
}

ExportTOExcel() 
{
  
   const ws:XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.table.nativeElement);
   const wb:XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
   console.log(this.table.nativeElement);
  /* save to file */
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'SheetJS.xlsx');     
} 
 
}
```

I am using npm i XLSX and getting some error.

**ERROR:**

> > Bad range (0): A1:A0
>
> [object Error]{description: "Bad range (...", message: "Bad range (...", name: "Error", ngDebugContext: Object {...}, stack: "Error: Bad ..."}

what is wrong here?

is there any other way to export excel from Angular Material Table, I also need the pagination for my table.

Answer (score 1):

SheetJS XLSX is not compatible with Angular Material 5 & above because it reads table tag where as from material 5 on wards the mat-table is used.

Comment: Thanks for the response . I have manage to make it work now. I have import the file server import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'; and export the same JSON data which I use as my table data....

Answer (score 1):

Too late, but I try...
I found the same problem and fixed this way:
Change HTML tags from

`<mat-table...>...</mat-table>`  to `<table mat-table...>...</table>`

`<mat-header-cell ...>...</mat-header-cell>` to `<th mat-header-cell....>...</th>`

`<mat-cell...>...</mat-cell>` to `<td mat-cell ...>...</td>`

That's all, XLSX not recognize material tags, but the material attributes.